# overriding an interface method not marked as virtual

Tags: c#, overriding, virtual

I'm writing a log4net appender.  They have an AppenderSkeleton class which implements IAppender:

```
public abstract class AppenderSkeleton : IBulkAppender, 
    IAppender, IOptionHandler
```

They way the AppenderSkeleton class works is they implement the DoAppend() method of IAppender and do a bunch of work for you, like calling the filter chain, and then call an abstract method called Append().  While this is reasonable, I would like to execute some of my code before the filters run.  I could implement the IAppender interface myself but at first I figured I would just try to override DoAppend() in my derived class, do my stuff, and then call base.DoAppend().  It was at this point where I noticed the AppenderSkeleton didn't mark DoAppend() as virtual since I got a compiler error indicating I couldn't override the method since it wasn't marked virtual.

I then had my class derive from IAppender and explicitly implemented the IAppender.DoAppend() method.  I was surprised that the code compiled without issues.  Below is my DoAppend() method:

```
void IAppender.DoAppend(LoggingEvent evnt)
{
    .
    .
    .
    base.DoAppend(evnt);
}
```

I haven't tried running it yet but wondering if someone might now what the runtime will end up doing with this implementation?

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Your class is not *derive* from `IAppender`, it implements `IAppender`. It directly derive from `object`, and object has no method `DoAppend`, so `base.DoAppend` is an error.

Comment: Your method will only be called if it's cast as `IAppender`. If it's cast as `AppenderSkeleton`, your code will not run.

Comment: I really just wanted to answer run it.

Comment: _"I haven't tried running it yet"_ -- why not? Doesn't that seem to you like the _best_ way to get your answer? Stack Overflow isn't here to do things you could easily do yourself. If you want to know what the code does, compile it and run it. If you want help understanding something or can't get something to work, post a good [mcve] and a _specific_ question. See also [ask].

Comment: Just didn't get around to running it yet.  However, no matter what the outcome of running it I would still have had the question why doing what I did was able to get rid of the compiler error.

Comment: @Rob, thanks, that's what I assumed but was still surprised that what I did was able to get around the compiler error and essentially, if you're correct, will give me the behavior I'm looking for as I believe methods are called on the interface IAppender not the AppenderSkeleton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rob's answer is right - which method (base or derived) is called would depend on how you invoked it.  That would make it rather fragile code.

What I'd recommend is to use composition and not inheritance.  Don't make your class inherit from AppenderSkeleton, make it contain an instance of AppenderSkeleton and use its methods where you choose to.

Visual Studio even has a quick "Implement interface through private variable" option if you declare a private variable that implements one of the interfaces your class also implements.  It quickly generates a proxy pattern for your class, calling the corresponding methods on the private member.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about using containment (composition) and that might be the way I go.  I don't want to have to rely on implementing my own DoAppend() by using reflector and copying the logic from there.  That's why I initially tried to find a way to override the AppenderSkeleton DoAppend() and surprisingly I got it to compile without error so was somewhat surprised by that.  I guess if I know that all code using the instance will be treating it as an instance of IAppender as opposed to AppenderSkeleton then it should work with what I have done already.

Answer (score 0):

If someone has not marked his method as virtual, then there is no way to override this. The only option is to implement your own `IAppender`.
Also, note that you do not override interface methods, you implement them.

However, you even do not need to override this method.
According to documentation, `DoAppend`

> performs threshold checks and invokes filters before delegating actual logging to the subclasses specific Append method.

You don't need to override `DoAppend` method, since it describes the generic algorithm.
It is sort of [Template method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

You need to override `Append` method which is abstract:

```
protected override void Append(LogginEvent loggingEvent)
{
    // Your actions here
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  But I either need to override DoAppend() or implement IAppender myself as I want to run code before the filters are run.  I didn't want to have to re-implement all the code that DoAppend() does and therefore was trying to find a way to allow me to implement DoAppend() and do the work I needed to do and then call the base class's DoAppend().